# Refactoring if elsif else or in Ruby block

Tags: ruby, refactoring

```ruby
def main_method
    new_array = []

    some_array.each do |foo|
      if (method_01? foo) || (method_02? foo) || (method_03? foo) || (method_04? foo) || (method_05? foo)
      else
        new_array << foo
      end
    end
  end
```

Is there a better way to write the above code without or (||) and without elsif conditions?

Is looping thru a hash appropriate for such refactoring?

Comment: Each method (method_01?, method_02?...)  contains a calculation that edits the `foo` and adds back to `new_array` if none of the methods match then the element is added the to the `new_array`

Comment: It is rather really practice to define questionmark-methods which have side-effects, i.e. which change data outside of their local method scope. This is generally unexpected and can cause you a lot of grief later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this would help?

*I've updated my answer for splitting array on two groups.*

```
def main_method
  methods = [:method1, :method2, :method3]
 non_passed_elems, passed_elems = some_array.partition do |elem|
    methods.none? do |method|
      send(method, elem)
    end
  end
  passed_elems.each{ |t| method_for_passed_elems(t) }
  non_passed_elems.each{ |t| method_for_non_passed_elems(t) }
end
```

Comment: It looks like you reversed the logic. I think he wants all elements where none of the methods returns true. `[false, false].select {|e| [:method01, :method02].none? {|m| send(m, e)}}`

Comment: how do you handle the `else` part after all the calls to the functions are made?

Comment: @JonasElfström is right, you need to use `any?` instead of `none?`.

Comment: @Баста Instead of creating a new array this filters the original array to return the elements you were looking for. This is more idiomatic Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

It would be hard to come up with an alternative to the `||`s without knowing your specific use case, but the iteration can be cleaned up a good deal using `#reject`:

```
def main_method
  some_array.reject do |foo|
    method_01?(foo) || method_02?(foo) # ... etc.
  end
end
```

`#reject` will yield each member to the block and return an array that contains only the members that returned `false`. In other words, only the members that return `false` to *all* of methods 1-5.

Comment: Wouldn't this still have cyclomatic complexity, since it's contain `||` inside the block? and how would it handle the `else` condition? Thank you!

Comment: The `else` condition is empty in your example so I figured you wouldn't need it.

The complexity of your code will be _at least_ as complex as your requirement. And your requirement seems to be to return an array in which the members return `false` to all of 5 methods. You need to `||` all of those results somewhere, so be explicit about it!

Answer (score 0):

More concise way:

```
checkers = (1..5).map {|i| "method_%02d" % i}  # too lazy ;)
new_array = some_array.select {|e| !checkers.any? {|m| e.send m}}
```

Still pretty readable & obvious.